# Changing font size in itextsharp table

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

Im attempting to view a table in a PDF file using iTextSharp. I've figured out how to add the table, and make the PDF file open off a button click, but the table font is too big, and words are wrapped making them hard to read. I've entered this code, but nothing happens to the tables font.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlServerCe;
using System.IO;
using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;

namespace Lewis_Warby_Airbrushing
{
    public partial class selectedorderForm : Form
    {
        public selectedorderForm(string strValue)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            textBox1.Text = strValue;

        }
        DataTable dt;
        private void selectedorderForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlCeConnection con = new SqlCeConnection(@"Data Source=|DataDirectory|\LWADataBase.sdf;");
            SqlCeDataAdapter sda = new SqlCeDataAdapter("select * from orderTBL ", con);

            dt = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dt);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
            DataView dv = new DataView(dt);
            dv.RowFilter = "[Order Number] like '%" + textBox1.Text.Trim() + "%'";
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dv;
        }

        private void pdfBTN_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            iTextSharp.text.Font fontTitle = FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 18, iTextSharp.text.Font.BOLD, BaseColor.BLACK);


            Document doc = new Document(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.A4, 10, 10, 10, 10);


            PdfWriter wri = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream("PurchaseOrder-"+textBox1.Text+".pdf", FileMode.Create));
            doc.Open();


            Paragraph title = new Paragraph("PURCHASE ORDER " + textBox1.Text +"\n Lewis Warby Airbrushing\n", fontTitle);
            title.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
            doc.Add(title);

            title.SpacingAfter = 15f;







            iTextSharp.text.Font fontTable = FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 5, iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.BLACK);

            PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(dataGridView1.Columns.Count);
            table.SpacingBefore = 45f;
            table.TotalWidth = 216f;
            table.DefaultCell.Phrase = new Phrase() { Font = fontTable };

            for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; j++)
            {
                table.AddCell(new Phrase(dataGridView1.Columns[j].HeaderText));

            }

            table.HeaderRows = 1;

            for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                for (int k = 0; k < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; k++)
                {
                    if (dataGridView1[k, i].Value != null)
                    {
                        table.AddCell(new Phrase(dataGridView1[k, i].Value.ToString()));
                    }
                }
            }



            doc.Add(table);




            doc.Close();

            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("PurchaseOrder-"+textBox1.Text+".pdf");


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try giving this a read: http://forums.asp.net/t/1806360.aspx?how+to+set+font+size+in+itextsharp+pdf+table+

Comment: Its as if i have to set each cell individually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding font to Phrase constructors:

```
for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; j++)
{
    table.AddCell(new Phrase(dataGridView1.Columns[j].HeaderText,fontTable));

}

//..

for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    for (int k = 0; k < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; k++)
    {
         if (dataGridView1[k, i].Value != null)
         {
              table.AddCell(new Phrase(dataGridView1[k, i].Value.ToString(),fontTable));
         }
     }
}
```

Check this link for more info about Chunkc, Phrases etc. http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/82/iTextSharp-Adding-Text-with-Chunks-Phrases-and-Paragraphs