# How to change the table font size

Tags: c#, .net, itext

I am using iText 5.5.10 and I have tried to change the default font size for the cells in a table like this:

```
table.DefaultCell.Phrase = new Phrase() { Font = fontTable };
```

This didn't have any effect. The default font was still 12pt Helvetica.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23598192/changing-font-size-in-itextsharp-table

Comment: You're not telling us which version you're using, hence the question can not be answer unambiguously.

Comment: I tried this.But not working .table.DefaultCell.Phrase = new Phrase() { Font = fontTable };

Comment: Version is 5.5.10.0 @Bruno

Comment: What you have tried, can't work. You can't set the default font for a table. Your code can't work because the `Phrase` of the `DefaultCell` is never used.

Comment: I created a method , private Phrase SetFontSize(string text)
 { Font fontNormal = new Font(Font.FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 10, Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.BLACK);
 return new Paragraph(new Chunk(text, fontNormal));
} and called it as table.AddCell(SetFontSize("File")); Now it worked

Answer (score 2):

In iText 7, it is simple. You can define the font size at a top-level element, and it is inherited by the objects added to that object.

If you're still using iText 5, the default font is always Helvetica and the default font size is always 12. You can't change it, but you can create a helper method that creates `PdfPCell`, `Paragraph` or `Phrase` instances in which a specific font with a specific size is used.

In other words: the answer depends on which version of iText you're using. If it's 7, the answer is: that's easy. If it's 5, the answer is: you can't change the default.

Comment: But when I get ITextSharp in .NET as a nuget package it shows this 5.5.10 as the version and last updated in 2016/10/10 . There is not showing any version 7

Comment: It's as if you didn't visit the iText web site to get the latest information... Please take a look at [the Jump-Start tutorial](http://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-jump-start-tutorial-net/itext-7-jump-start-tutorial-net-version).

Comment: If you search for "itextsharp" on NuGet.org, you will find iText 7 Community on the second page. That's not our fault, that's just how NuGet works. iText 7 will move up soon enough when more people start using it. On the other hand, if you search for "itext" on NuGet.org, then iText 7 Community is the third result on the first page.

Comment: Something I take away from this: in the package description for iTextSharp 5.5.11, there needs to be a mention of iText 7, which uses a new name (without the -sharp). However, iTextSharp is packaged for NuGet by a third party (while iText 7 is packaged by iText Software), so some coordination with that third party is required. *adds DEV ticket*

Comment: Yes agree.That's why I could find it in Nuget.I just searched as ITextSharp. There is not mentioned about IText7 in that content page

Comment: @LahiruD iTextSharp is packaged for NuGet by a third party, not by iText Software. We will ask the third party to update the package description for iTextSharp 5.5.11. Meanwhile I updated the description on the NuGet website itself. Please tell me if this is clear enough for you. Text formatting is not possible in NuGet package descriptions, nor are hyperlinks.

Comment: Yes.Thank you for the clarification @AmedeeVanGasse